# Is there any way to get the default duration of animations is iOS?

Tags: objective-c

Does anyone know about a list of default animation durations in iOS?
For example:

- How long does it take for the keyboard to slide down/up?
- How long does it take for the status bar to fade away?
- What is the duration of all of UITableView's default row animations? etc.

Is there any way to get these values? A list that contains them or maybe through code?

I would really appreciate any kind of help,
Thank you,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don’t think there is a definitive list in the API. In some cases you can observe a notification such as `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` with the `UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey` giving you the precise time value. Other times you simply should not depend on those times in your interface or tune the timing by hand, and accept that you might have to tweak it with future iOS updates.

Comment: Thank you very much, that UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey helped a lot